# How to show json root for object in rabl when config.include_json_root = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I'm using the rabl gem in my rails API and at the beginning  I set `config.include_json_root = false` and I've been working without the root of the json response but now I have a new resource and just in that resource I need to get the root.

I was trying something like:

`object @myobj, :root => 'foo'`

But that's not working at all.

How can I add the json root only to this rabl file and leave everything else without any modification?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
object false
child(@myobj) { 
  attribute :attr1 :attr2
}
```

I was scratching my head for a minute until someone pointed this out to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
node(:foo) do |myobj|
      {
        :apy => myobj.apy,
        :apr => myobj.apr
      }
end
```